# Adding Sum of fields of two tables giving strange result in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, reporting, crystal-reports-2008

I am using SAP crystal reports for Visual studio.

I have two tables (TableA, TableB). with fields PriceA, PriceB.

TableA
Field : PriceA ={20,40,40};

TableB
Field : PriceB ={50.40,60};

I have created a formula in my main report **Formula1 = Sum(TableA.PriceA) + Sum(TableB.PriceB)**

But instead of getting result as @Formula1 =250. It is giving the incorrect result like '1050' (not exact).

How can i get a correct result in this case.

Comment: Where are you calculating the summary and where you are placing it in report?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest inserting a summary of each field (right-click on field -> Insert -> Summary) and then creating a sum of the two using a formula.