# SUM of 2 Columns using Crystal Report in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

My table name is "accounting"

it has two columns named "Debit" and "Credit"

Is it possible to have the sum of these two columns?

example:

```
               INPUT:                      
      Debit              Credit                     
       200        +      -100      
       300        +      -300   
       500        +      -400      
     --------          ----------                  
      1000               -800
```

I want it to appear like this in my Crystal Report:

```
Debit              Credit              TOTAL                    
  200               -100                100
  300               -300                 0 
  500               -400                100
--------          ----------          ---------        
  1000               -800               200
```

I dont know what FORMULA I should use in Crystal Report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is good if you this done in sqlserver as add a column with summary like

```
select 
    Debit, Credit, Debit+Credit as Total
from yourtable
```

If you wish in crystal report side, then also it is possible.

Add one variable and write this as below and put near this fields in detail section.

```
{@yourtablename.DebitField} + {@yourtablename.creditField} //I forgot the syntax, please change aproopriate.
```

[Adding Sum of fields of two tables giving strange result in Crystal Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692465/adding-sum-of-fields-of-two-tables-giving-strange-result-in-crystal-report)

http://vbcity.com/forums/t/154231.aspx